# VS 2017 Access Denied when opening vs 2015 solution

Tags: c#, wpf, installation

I was trying to run a wpf app which has been created in Visual Studio 2015 using visual studio  2017 enterprise but I am getting this error below:

[image: not a funny error]

I am not sure what it means who should I have to provide access in fact I am wonder if I should provide access to something

Comment: That's in the vs2017 tree. It's usually associated with a user. Your user? What exactly did you do to get to this stage? There was a sln and it's contents somewhere and you did what?

Comment: Did you try a clean, to ensure nothing is old versions of anything and everything is compiling OK?

Answer (score 2):

Try running the Visual Studio 2017 in administrator mode and also check if your project folder is set to read only and change it if so.

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan that is exactly what I did in at once but it did not work !! any other idea ?

Comment: In addition the app is a wpf app and seems the issue happens only when runing wpf´s

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like your are trying to run code that is compiled. Instead of running the solution. Hence the L3r.UI.exe. Are you sure your not running compiled code? Which should not need to be ran in Visual Studio. Also I have never seen it where there is an L3r.UI. with two dots in the name. Wonder if the naming might be throwing it off.  Usually, exe files are in the form of UI.exe